# Global Variable used inside function's if statement seems to be blank JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am just curious about why a variable is consider to be blank when it is already defined as global variable.

```
var name = "Richard";
function showName(){
    if(name){   // the name is already defined as global variable but why the condition is false ?
        var name="Jack";
        console.log(name);
    }

}
showName()  // its blank
console.log(name); //display Richard
```

If I changed the statement of `if(name)` to `if(!name)` then it works as expected. Why the "name" is returning blank since it has already a global variable defined with value.

I am just trying to understand the JavaScript. I am learning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have declared `name` as a local variable to the function, [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `name` variable.

Anywhere you declare a variable with `var` in a closure, it creates and [hoists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) a local variable by the name, with an initial value of `undefined` (a falsey value, so the if block does not run).

Remove the `var` in `var name="Jack";`, you only need `var` for declaring the variable, not re-assigning the variable.

```js
var name = "Richard";
function showName(){
    if(name){
        name="Jack";
        console.log(name);
    }

}
showName()
console.log(name);
```

Comment: But the if statement is used before the local variable is created. So it must be using the global variable right ? Why it returns blank ?

Comment: @Santosh No, `var` is not block-scoped. Check out hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: 'Anywhere you declare a variable with var in a closure, it creates and hoists '  Now I understand. Thanks for making me understand. I read the topic hoist too :)